# set up nuxt 3 as front-end with express as back-end for server side rendring

Tags: express, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

i just start learning the **back-end** and i choose express for nodejs as a back-end and switch from vue.js to nuxt.js as it server side rendring but i can't understand how to connect the **front-end** (**nuxt 3**) with the back-end (**express**) (i am not talking about to futsh data but how to set up the project).

i asked **chatgpt** about that, and i end with this result that the best structure for this project (nuxt + express) is like this :

```
front-end/         <-- Nuxt.js project folder (the frontend folder)
  ├─ assets/
  ├─ components/
  ├─ layouts/
  ├─ pages/
  ├─ plugins/
  ├─ static/
  ├─ store/
  ├─ nuxt.config.ts
  ├─ package.json
  └─ back-end/         <-- Express.js project folder (the backend folder)
        └─ server.js      <-- Express server file
```

this is my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "project-ssr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev:back": "nodemon back-end/server.js",
    "dev:front": "nuxt dev",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongoose": "^7.3.0",
    "validator": "^13.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.8.0",
    "nuxt": "^3.5.2",
    "nuxt-icon": "^0.4.1"
  }
}
```

i start by add this file to the folder then run "npm i" to install all the dependencies, after that i add the back-end folder (server.js ...ext) after that i add nuxt folders (nuxt.config.ts, pages/, components/, ...ext), then i run "npm run dev:front" it works fine, then "npm run dev:back" it works fine aslo, after that i add nuxt to server.js as chatgpt and outher sources told me like that :

```
const express = require("express");
const { createNuxt } = require("nuxt");

const path = require("path");
const db = require("./database");
const users = require("./users/routes");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const config = require(path.resolve(__dirname, "../nuxt.config.ts"))
config.dev = false

const nuxt = createNuxt(config)

app.use(nuxt.render)

app.listen(port = 50000, async () => {
    console.log(`1 - server listening on port ${port}`);
    try {
        await db.connect();

        app.use("/api/users", users);

        app.use("*", (req, res, next) => {
            res.send("welcome to the server");
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

and then edit nuxt.config.ts to be like that :

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: [
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss",
    "nuxt-icon"
  ],
  ssr: true,
  css: [
    "~/assets/css/tailwind.css"
  ]
});
```

then run "npm run dev:back" again, this error shows up on the terminal :
[image: error]

i understand that the nuxt package does not have an exports field in its package.json file. This is because the package is not designed to be used as a module.

**but for now i can't understand for to set up the project where nuxt is the fron-end (for server side rendring) with the express as back-end.**

as i said before i just a beginner so **feel free to criticize my code and my understanding**, **please correct me if you think my code or my understanding or anything is wronged**, and thank you alot.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, its to late =). You need to use two workspaces and packages.json files. See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).